# Re-assign accepted answer years later?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

A few years ago I asked [Remove or prevent sidebar from opening by default on Adobe Reader](https://superuser.com/q/902758/259665) and received a superb response.

A recent update to the software in question nullifies this accepted answer and a [new answer](https://superuser.com/a/1173789/259665) has arisen to being correct.

I am looking for community guidance as to whether or not I should accept the newcomer as the correct answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yup. Best answers change sometimes. Considering its not version specific, I'd add a note on the question and switch.

Answer (score 12):

I would actually make an argument somewhat different from [that of Journeyman Geek](https://meta.superuser.com/a/12069/53590).

The reason is simple: **The question *specifies a version* of Acrobat Reader.** It even did so back in April 2015 when it was originally posted.

**An answer for a much later version that works differently from the version being asked about isn't an answer to the question that is being asked, and thus by definition cannot be the most useful answer to the question that is being asked.**

- If you are **happy** with the question being about "any version of Acrobat Reader with a sidebar superficially similar to the one in 2015.007.20033", then the question should be edited to explicitly state that, or at the very least not explicitly state a version number other than for the purposes of being an example.
- If you want to keep the question **specific** to the version that you originally asked about, the person who posted the answer should be encouraged to post it as a self-answer to an updated question for the version that the answer is about, preserving the integrity of the original question.

Comment: I've considered your assessment before posting this question. The original intent of including a version number is to mitigate the chance that someone using an ancient version of Reader doesn't make a comment like "Mine doesn't do that you stupids, hurr durr". I'd like to keep the question open as a central repository for SEO purposes because the issue crosses version borders but the solution is just Adobe's attempt at smoke n' mirrors. I think I will remove the version number. When Journeyman said "Considering its not version specific" I think he was referring to the presence of the issue.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That particular type of comment would in my opinion be a prime candidate for flagging as "not constructive".

Comment: That specific comment was for illustrative purposes only; it could be worded more nicely and still have the same effect. Comments like that have the ability to derail a question and create a mob mentality. I wanted my question to generate some steam and plow through to get good answers. Anyways, I've updated the question to use "presently 2015.007.20033". Do you think that will suffice or should I opt to remove the version number completely?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus IMO, the version shown in the screenshot and the version being asked about should at least match. You could approach that in several ways, but I would probably go with something much like what I already included in my answer, maybe not including the word "superficially".